# Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject'

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, gluon

I know this has been asked muliple times and i have been searching for 5 hours and none of the solutions are working for me.. Do i need to be connected to the internet everytime i want to create a gluon project in eclipse?

WHen i am offline this is the error that i get:

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip'.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created your project and run it (or installed on your device, i.e. running `androidInstall`), you have locally all the dependencies required, so after that you can run without Internet connection unless you need to change any of those dependencies (if there is an update of any of them, for instance).

On Eclipse, you just need to add the option `--offline` to the task you are running.

In the Gradle Tasks window, select the task, and with right click select `Open Gradle Run Configuration`. Go to the Arguments tab and add `--offline`.

[image: offline option]

Don't forget to remove this option when you are back online.

It is advisable that you add also `--info`, to get a more verbose output and find out about possible issues while running the task:

[image: info option]

Comment: Thanks sir... but my problem i everytime i start a new gluon project i heve to be connected to the internet... Is it normal?

Comment: While is the recommended approach, you don't need it if you have all the required dependencies already installed.

Comment: Yeah.. it seems that i will have to live with it.. Because i cant get rid of this error... "org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip'."  But anyway... I am have a problem trying to import the cache plugin in eclipse mentioned in [this](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/fiftystates/) its like it doesn't exist

Comment: But if you are connected it works fine? When offline, when do you see that message: creating the project or running it?

Comment: If you run from command line (root of project) `gradlew android --offline --info` connected to internet , does it work? And if you run it now offline?

Comment: It says 'gradlew' is not recognized as operable program or batch file."

Comment: On Linux/Mac run `./gradlew ...`, on Windows `gradlew.bat`. If that doesn't work, check its permissions.

Comment: Ok... But that i can check later... Right now im more concerned with the cache plugin that i cant import from [this](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/fiftystates/) tutorial